# Unable to bind form property - Angular 14/Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular14

Apologies if this has been answered, I've looked around for solutions and haven't found one that works yet.

I'm trying to collect data in a form ngModel to bind the input to DepartmentName but it's not getting the string input in the form:

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title >{{ModalTitle}}</h2>
<ng-container *ngIf="DepartmentId === 0">
  <form name="add">
  <mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography" id="add-edit-modal">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Department Name" [(ngModel)]="DepartmentName"/>
      
    </mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-dialog-actions align="end">
      <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
      <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true" type="button" name="add" cdkFocusInitial (click)="addDepartment()">Add</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
  </form>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="DepartmentId !== 0">
  <mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography" id="add-edit-modal">
    <form name="add" onsubmit="addDepartment()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Department Name" [(ngModel)]="DepartmentName"/>
    </form>
      
    </mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-dialog-actions align="end">
      <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
        <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="true" cdkFocusInitial>Submit</button>
    </mat-dialog-actions>
</ng-container>
```

Here is the component collecting the department name and calling the API:

```
import { SharedService } from './../../shared.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-edit-dep',
  templateUrl: './add-edit-dep.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-edit-dep.component.css']
})
export class AddEditDepComponent implements OnInit {
  ModalTitle: string = this.data.ModalTitle;
  DepartmentId?: number = 0;
  DepartmentName?: string = '';

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private service: SharedService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.data.dep) {
      this.DepartmentId = this.data.dep.DepartmentId;
      this.DepartmentName = this.data.dep.DepartmentName;
    } 
  }

  addDepartment() {
    const val = {DepartmentId: this.DepartmentId,
                  DepartmentName: this.DepartmentName}
    this.service.addDepartment(val).subscribe(res => {
      alert(res.toString());
    })
  }
}
```

I've tried adding ngOnChanges as well in order to see if any data is updating, but nothing appears to be happening.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Get the data entered on UI or log the server response?
It'd be helpful to see the service

Comment: It's not an issue with the service. I'm trying to bind the input with ngModel to the property DepartmentName and it's not connecting.